# CPP: avoiding macro expansion of a macro function parameter

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

what I'd like to do (for logging purposes) is something like this:

This code has been written to show my problem, actual code is complex and yes, I have good reasons to use macros even on C++ =)

```
# define LIB_SOME 1
# define LIB_OTHER 2

# define WHERE "at file #a, line #l, function #f: "
// (look for syntax hightlighting error at SO xd)
# define LOG_ERROR_SIMPLE(ptr, lib, str) ptr->log ("ERROR " str \
                                                   " at library " #lib);
# define LOG_ERROR(ptr, lib, str) LOG_ERROR_SIMPLE(ptr, lib, WHERE str)

LOG_ERROR_SIMPLE (this, LIB_SOME, "doing something")
LOG_ERROR (this, LIB_OTHER, "doing something else")
```

`LOG_ERROR_SIMPLE()` writes the stringification of the lib parameter (a macro name surrounded by " ")

but then `LOG_ERROR` writes the stringification of the macro already expanded ("2"). this is expected, since lib got its expansion before expanding and calling `LOG_ERROR_SIMPLE`. but this is not what I need.

Basically my question is this: *how to avoid macro expansion of a macro function parameter when calling another macro function?*

There is a trick I use that avoids macro expansion:

```
  LOG_ERROR(ptr, lib, str, x) LOG_ERROR_SIMPLE(ptr, x##lib, WHERE str)

  LOG_ERROR(this, LIB_OTHER, "some error",)
```

(pasting x and lib produces `LIB_OTHER` and this value is used to call `LOG_ERROR_SIMPLE`, its not macro expanded before that call)

There is some way to obtain this same behaviour without using a trick?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm doing:

```
#include <cstdio>

#define FOO 1
#define BAR 2

#define LOG_SIMPLE(ptr, lib, str) printf("%s\n", #lib);
#define LOG(ptr, lib, str) LOG_SIMPLE(ptr, ##lib, str)

int main()
{
  LOG_SIMPLE(0, FOO, "some error");
  LOG(0, BAR, "some other error");
}
```

which prints out:

```
FOO
BAR
```

Works with MSVC2005 **but not with gcc/g++**.

---

EDIT: to make it work with gcc/g++ you can abuse variadic macros:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define FOO 1
#define BAR 2

#define LOG_SIMPLE(ptr, str, lib) printf("%s\n", #lib);
#define LOG(ptr, str, lib, ...) LOG_SIMPLE(ptr, str, lib##__VA_ARGS__)

int main()
{
  LOG_SIMPLE(0, "some error", FOO);
  LOG(0, "some other error", BAR);
  LOG(0, "some other error", FOO, BAR);
}
```

However, it's your discipline not to use the macro with too many parameters. MSVC2005 prints out

```
FOO
BAR
FOO2
```

while gcc prints out

```
FOO
BAR
FOOBAR
```

Comment: When using GCC's preprocessor (removing the `#include` that does not exist), I get the correct program on stdout, but an error message on stderr. t.c:11:1: error: pasting "," and "BAR" does not give a valid preprocessing token

Comment: Well, "doesn't work" is a bit strong. I did get a compilable program on stdout when I ran `gcc -E t.c`.

Comment: yes, pasting is a way of not expanding "whats inside of lib" in place and letting it reach LOG_SIMPLE. my previous example pasted lib with an empty parameter, yours pasted lib with the left comma (which of course is not totally "right"). I wonder if I could paste lib with "a special, hidden parameter" to get the same results as using an extra parameter in the macro, deliverately left empty for that purpose..

Comment: yes It's a good trick! unfortunately I'm already using variadic macros on LOG and LOG_SIMPLE.. I didn't specify it for the sake of simplicity, my fault. that's why I wasn't counting on __VA_ARGS__ as a source for paste nothing in a more elegant way.

Comment: i tried more today without much luck, do we decide you can't avoid expansion in the general case?

Comment: Gregory, AFAIK the only way for a macro name inside a macro function parameter to survive more than 1 level of nested macro function calls to get #param -> "MACRO_NAME" in the 2nd call or higher is the trick we discovered (either by pasting param with `__VA_ARGS__` or with another empty one) perhaps there is no solution apart from that trick.. perhaps we should suggest the CPP developers to implement an "empty value macro parameter" (lets call it `__EMPTY__`) as to be able to pass a macro parameter to other macro functions without expansion using the trick.. I think it'll be useful if they do

Comment: Getting it to work with gcc/clang etc: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610111/c-preprocessor-stringize-macro-and-identity-macro?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need the expanded lib aliases (i.e. '1' & '2') in your cpp macros, you could also use an enum instead of defined values.

Comment: Although I would have liked to find the solution to my macro expansion problem, you made me re-think one of its elements. I've changed my macro constants to enums, their name don't get macro expanded (since they aren't a macro) and now the problem is not solved, but its gone =)

Comment: Now I still want to solve it, but as far a my program is concerned, thanks to your suggestion I dont need to..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can.  What you could do, though, is add a layer of macro for it to unpeel in its place:

```
#define WRAP(x) x
#define LOG_ERROR(ptr, lib, str) LOG_ERROR_SIMPLE(ptr, lib, WHERE WRAP(str))
```

Comment: @kts Ooh, whaddya know.  I think of something, and the boffins at Boost are waaaaaay ahead of me.

Comment: neither WRAP or _IDENTITY works.. because (at least in CPP) it calls LOG_ERROR_SIMPLE with WRAP(<parameter expanded>) as the parameter, and not as "whats inside of the name but then not expanded"

Comment: Erk. In that case, I think you either foist LOG_ERROR(ptr, lib, WRAP(str)) on your users, or write out LOG_ERROR without referring to LOG_ERROR_SIMPLE.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. Use

```
#define LOG_ERROR(ptr, lib, str) LOG_ERROR_SIMPLE(ptr, ##lib, WHERE str)
```

On gcc
`LOG_ERROR(this, LIB_OTHER, "some error")`
yields
`this->log ("ERROR " "at file #a, line #l, function #f: " "some error" " at library " "LIB_OTHER");`

I would also remove the trailing ';' from your macro so that your code would look like:
`LOG_ERROR(this, LIB_OTHER, "some error");`

Comment: I think the OP wants to avoid the quoting of the argument hence the question. If "LIB_OTHER" was fine with him, I think he woudld'nt have asked in the first place

Comment: pasting lib with a comma gives this error: pasting "," and "LIB_OTHER" does not give a valid preprocessing token. is there some "neutral" character or hidden empty parameter I could use to paste lib with "something empty" and without errors?

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood your needs. BOOST_PP_EMPTY is a macro that expands to nothing. You could also try /**/ (thats an empty c-style comment in case markdown kills it)

Comment: Could you perhaps provide the desired output of your macro? Given LOG_ERROR(this, LIB_OTHER, "some error) what is the code you want generated?

Comment: @kts, its more on the macro side itself, the way it works and macro-expands things, not C code generation. I just want to stringify LIB_OTHER to obtain "LIB_OTHER".. of course, LIB_OTHER must be passed as a parameter and survive 2 levels of macro function calls, something not trivial to achieve.

Comment: @conejoroy Would `BOOST_PP_IDENTITY( LIB_OTHER )` suffice? It expands to a token that, when called with () returns the original argument.

Comment: @kts, no, inside of a macro function already called from the source, `LIB_OTHER` gets its expansion (from macro name to 2) before a second nested macro function is called, that is `BOOST_PP_IDENTITY( 2 )`... that macro function will always receive 2 instead of the macro name `LIB_OTHER`. thats the "2 level macro function call" problem I metioned, on the 2nd nested function call `LIB_OTHER` is always replaced by 2, there is no trivial workaround to avoid this, I just know one trick (pasting the parameter with another empty one, the result is `LIB_OTHER` and is left as is).