# C preprocessor: stringize macro and identity macro

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

I want to know the reason behind the output of this code. I couldn't come up with an answer.

```
#define f(a,b) a##b
#define g(a) #a
#define h(a) g(a)
void main()
{
   printf("%s %s",h(f(1,2)),g(f(1,2)));
}
```

PS: output is `12 f(1,2)`. I thought it was `12 12` or `f(1,2) f(1,2)`.

Comment: just to learn preprocessor working...

Comment: @cnicutar I think he found it here: http://cracktheinterviewers.blogspot.com/2012_03_01_archive.html

Comment: it was not written by me..it was asked in a test..

Comment: thanks for the link..i suppose it may be useful

Comment: The output might actually be different in different compilers. It is known that the preprocessors in GCC and Visual C++ works differently, and will produce different output for the same code.

Comment: @Dave That link just tells the answer, but doesn't answer why.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: SO it is undefined...but why will not the compiler work same way for first and second...i mean if it gives 12 for first one,compiler should do the logic same way for the second too right?

Comment: @vindhya: it's defined, but there are crappy compilers...

Comment: You can search for the flag on your compiler to stop after preprocessing. That way, you will know what the result of the macro expansion is.

Comment: The order of evaluation is important. Do the processor evaluate the "call" to `f` or `g` first?

Comment: but i want to know how to predict such things?why exactly there is the difference between the first and second?if going by order of evaluation first and second should be the same right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How, exactly, does the double-stringize trick work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751870/how-exactly-does-the-double-stringize-trick-work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
h(f(1,2))
```

`f(1,2)` is substituted for `a`. `a` is not the subject of a `#` or `##` operator so it's expanded to `12`. Now you have `g(12)` which expands to `"12"`.

```
g(f(1,2))
```

`f(1,2)` is substituted for `a`. The `#` operator applied to `a` prevents macro expansion, so the result is literally `"f(1,2)"`.

Comment: oh...ok thanks...i did not concentrate on the workings of # operator

Comment: @vindhya It's all a bloody mess.

Answer (score 3):

Just do the replacements.

```
h(f(1, 2)) -> g(12) -> "12"

g(f(1,2)) -> "f(1, 2)"
```

You should also see [here](http://c-faq.com/ansi/stringize.html).